# Elle est étudiante

Tags: grammaire

Its around a week or so since i started learning french , so I’m really noob (sorry for that)

And I’m using Duolingo
Here is a really basic question
If we want to say she or he is a student,
Why do we say “Elle est étudiante” instead of saying “Elle est une etudiante”

Cause I tried it and the app considered it as a mistake

Is there any more words like this ? And how we say students in french ? Only by using de before them ?

Thankyou

Comment: @Maroon yup thank you <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just of matter of idiomaticity.

For qualities, fonctions and  professions, the zero article form is used when you express that it is someone's quality, fonction, etc. ([français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-117489.php)), but only when you use the name or a pronoun.

- Il est dentiste. Elle est directrice. Jean est aviateur. Il est Chevalier de la Légion d'Honneur. Il est artiste. Elle est étudiante.

When you use what is called the "présentatif « c'est »" you must use the article.

- C'est **un** dentiste. C'est **une** directrice. C'est **un** aviateur. C'est **un** Chevalier de la Légion d'Honneur. C'est **un** artiste. C'est **une** étudiante.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration